# change built in CSS attribute

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a component which I'm inherits (including its css style) and I would like to change one of its attributes

This is the current CSS:

```css
.captcha-main-image {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<img class ="captcha-main-image" id="captchaImage" src="">
```

I would like to change its width value. 
This element is being generated by a different source and I can't ask the developer to change its value.
Any chance I can do that by using `!important` somehow?

Comment: Of course you can do it with !important but you can also do it by using Javascript. The only thing is "When do you want to change the width ?"

Comment: Look for thee class the original component is using. And then override that class with `!important` tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of [Angular's view isolation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#view-encapsulation), you can override it only if you put the overrides in application's main style sheet.

In your application's styles.css, which is your application's main scss file - the one that is mentioned in agular.json, add the override:

```
.captcha-main-image {
   width: <your-value>
}
```

Typically, the `!important` is not required. Use it only if required.

Answer (score 1):

You could add the class with max-width attribute to limit the width, e.g:

```
.captcha-main-image {
   max-width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: `max-width` does not override width, it only puts an upper limit on width's value.

Comment: Yes wording wasn't correct but outcome will have the desired effect, assuming 'width' value set at 100%. Will amend thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to override class within component adding `!important` will help
Or if you want to override the css outside of that component use `::ng-deep .captcha-main-image` can do.

Comment: `ng-deep` is deprecated.